# Migrate from WildFly to Google AppEngine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, wildfly

I'm not a Java coder, but I have experience with Python GAE and am trying to migrate a working WildFly (aka JBoss?) Java web app to Google AppEngine.

### I started with:

1. A WAR file for the app and
2. a standalone.xml file to configure a `datasource` for the app (a Postgres server).

Using these, I can stand up the app on, say, a VM just fine.

### I migrated by:

1. Unzipping the WARs normally fed to WildFly to create a GAE subfolder: `myproject/myapp`
2. Creating appropriate GAE files in META-INF and WEB-INF subfolders (project level and service level) [per the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/configuration-files).
3. Deployed: `appcfg.sh update myapp`

While the app deployed, it doesn't run render any page nor does it produce a GAE log (other than the request resulted in a 200 response).

### I'm failing because:

1. `standalone.xml` is unused - how do I tell GAE what DB to use? [I think in `pom.xml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/cloud-sql/), but the XML looks quite different.  Here's my standalone.xml snippet:

   ```
   <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/postgresql" pool-name="postgresql" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
       <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres</connection-url>
       <driver>postgresql</driver>
       <security>
           <user-name>myuser</user-name>
           <password>mypassword/password>
       </security>
   </datasource>
   ```
2. How else?  What other hazards should I be looking for?

Answer (score 1):

If you are considering to use Google App Engine (standard environment), you must consider other type of database. Usually, applications in that GAE environment use cloud-based databases. You cannot use a "localhost" postgresql database. You may consider the [Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/api-overview) and the [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/) instead.

The standard GAE uses a sandbox that limits the libraries and functions you can use. You may check more information at

- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments
- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/runtime

The flexible GAE and other Google Cloud offerings such as the Google Compute give you containers or virtual machines where you do not have a sandbox and/or you can install software. If you are interested on using wildfly you may consider that other non-free services.

- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/
- https://console.cloud.google.com/launcher/details/bitnami-launchpad/wildfly